# JQuery UI Date Picker won't appear in Chrome

Tags: jquery-ui

Works in FF/IE, not Chrome or Safari.

```
<div id="date"></div>
$("#date").datepicker();
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Have you tried to open developer tools in Chrome to see if there are any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably something in your code. But usually people use the datepicker with an input. But that piece of code you are using does work fine in chrome
http://jsbin.com/uceku3/2

Comment: For some reason it needed to be on document ready or chrome wasn't picking it up =/